# About the way of extracting/viewing the contents of a download jar file from the Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to extract/view the contents of a download jar file from the Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add it the build path of a Java project you can browser a JAR file's contents in Eclipse.

I don't know if you can extract a JAR file's contents in Eclipse.  (I don't understand why you would want / need to do that!)  But you can extract a JAR file from the command line using the `jar` command ... or an ordinary ZIP file extractor.